# Must the Antlr generation tool version match the runtime version?

Tags: antlr4

I have a project with a custom grammar, and I'm using using Antlr4 to generate the parser. I also include a third party lib, which just so happens to use Antlr4 to implement the stuff that *they* are doing.

At runtime I get an warning message that says "ANTLR Tool version 4.x.x used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.y.y". The third party expects 4.x.x, while my project is using 4.y.y.

My question is, how critical is this warning, and can I ignore it? Or more specifically, can the Antlr generated code actually break or misbehave when using the same major Antlr version for both generation and runtime?

(Alternatively, if there is a way to use the same version that suits both the third party and my own project simultaneously, please share how to do this. The IntelliJ Antlr plugin is shipped w/ 4.13.1, while my third party lib dependency is at 4.11.1. Seems the the generator and the runtime should operate with independent versions, and the generator should target a specific major runtime version.)

Comment: There is some compatibility between versions, but it depends. For example, Java allows for patch version differences https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/d25d421780286e3de0714831a5f82eca59234249/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/RuntimeMetaData.java#L144. For Go, it's the complete version string. https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/d25d421780286e3de0714831a5f82eca59234249/runtime/Go/antlr/v4/recognizer.go#L58 . I would think a patch version would not cause problems. It depends on how the tool and runtime were changed. So, it's best to use the same version.